# FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Facing this issue in production with Angular 5 when connected to custom domain, while application works fine on myproject.firebaseapp.com

@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

And data is not loaded on application

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.6.3",
"angular-calendar": "^0.21.3",
"angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^4.6.2",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.4.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"typescript": "^2.6.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

},

Comment: if the code is the same on prod and local, this probably means a browser caching, in chrome try to open it in Incognito mode, in firefox try Private window